# Manual Stochastic Gradient Descent doesn't seem to converge to optimal solution

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gradient-descent, lasso-regression

dataset: [https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/Regression/cal_housing.html](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/%7Eltorgo/Regression/cal_housing.html)

I am trying to implement SGD Regression on the 'California housing' dataset and chose 'medain_house_value' for training labels. I have learned that there is a unique threshold for the learning rate for each dataset, so reducing the learning rate made the code error free. But no matter how much I increase the number of epochs or decrease the learning rate eta, the RMSE doesn't even go near that of SciKit-Learn's SGDRegressor. Why? Did the model get stuck at a local minimum? Why is my code so slow in comparison with sklearn's SGDRegressor?

**Note** : You can run the code as it is without making any changes.

```py
#SGD ElasticNet Regression with early stopping
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet, SGDRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import tarfile
import urllib.request

def rng():
    return np.random.default_rng(time.time_ns())

def learning_schedule(t):
    t0 = 0.09
    t1 = 50
    return t0/(t1+t)

def load_housing_data():
    tarball_path = Path("datasets/housing.tgz")
    if not tarball_path.is_file():
        Path("datasets").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        url = "https://github.com/ageron/data/raw/main/housing.tgz"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, tarball_path)
        with tarfile.open(tarball_path) as housing_tarball:
            housing_tarball.extractall(path="datasets")
    return pd.read_csv(Path("datasets/housing/housing.csv"))

f = load_housing_data()

#data cleaning
f = pd.get_dummies(f)
fills = {}
for i in f:
    fills[i] = f[i].median()
f.fillna(fills, inplace=True)

#pre-processing
y = np.reshape(f['median_house_value'].copy().to_numpy(), (-1,1))
data = f.drop(['median_house_value'], axis=1).to_numpy()
scaler = StandardScaler()
polyf = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3, include_bias=True)
data_poly = polyf.fit_transform(data)
data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data_poly)
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(data_scaled, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

max_epochs = 10
m = len(xtrain)
alpha = 50
r = 0.7
theta = rng().normal(scale=10, size=(xtrain.shape[1],1))
gcount = 0
stop_threshold = 100
old_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(xtest.dot(theta),ytest))
eta = 0.001

#training
for i in range(max_epochs):
    xy = np.concatenate((xtrain,ytrain),axis=1)
    rng().shuffle(xy,axis=0)
    Xi = xy[:,:-1]
    yi = np.reshape(xy[:,-1],(-1,1))
    for k in range(m):
        gradients = 2 * np.reshape(Xi[k],(1,-1)).T.dot(np.reshape(Xi[k],(1,-1)).dot(theta)-np.reshape(yi[k],(-1,1))) + 2*alpha*theta
        eta = learning_schedule(i*m + k)
        theta = theta - eta*gradients
        predictions = xtest.dot(theta)
        new_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(ytest, predictions))
        diff = new_rmse - old_rmse
        if diff <= 0:
            gcount+=1
        else:
            gcount=0
        if gcount == stop_threshold:
            break
        old_rmse = new_rmse
    if gcount == stop_threshold:
        break

manual_SGD_RMSE = new_rmse
print (manual_SGD_RMSE)
#226714.85182093977 <------- manual SGD


sgdreg = SGDRegressor(alpha=50)
sgdreg.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(sgdreg.predict(xtest), ytest)))
#92286.31353592245 <------- SKLearn SGD

#tried increasing the epochs, decreasing eta (learning rate), increasing the gcount.
```

Comment: I'm new to ML and stuff, currently reading a book on it. Does investigating weight decay maybe help?